# Intel Turbo Boost does not work after standby S3 state

Tags: sleep, standby, intel-core-i5, turbo-boost

This feature does not work after standby S3 state (Standy, Sleep or Suspend to RAM). Tested with Intel CPUID and Turbo Boost Monitor. Although in hibernation it works and in hybrid sleep does not as well as log off, I use standby more than anything else. Playing with BIOS did not bring results. Drivers are all updated.

Specs:

- Dell Latitude E6420
- Windows 7 Enterprise
- i5-2520M
- BIOS A04